# how to display the contents of a text file in powerpoint using a macro

Tags: java, macros, powerpoint

i'm trying to make a powerpoint, and I have lots of text that I want to be displayed, is there a way to use a macro to read a document into powerpoint?

for example the document contains:

```
this is the first line  
this is the second line  
this is the third line
```

and I want the first line to be displayed, wait 10 secs and then display the 2nd line.

is this possible, if not with a macro, java??

cheers

Comment: Do you want to display it on a TextBox? What event should fire the display?

Comment: yeah I guess, has to be on automatic, so when slide starts

Comment: also i want to do it with pics, like a mini slideshow on one slide

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to display a slide with line one, then switch to a slide with line two (line one goes away) and so on, always one line per slide? 
Or do you want the slide to build, adding a line at a time until all the text from your file is visible at once?